# Tomcat java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter when trying to publish a Struts2 Dynamic Web App

Tags: eclipse, macos, tomcat, struts2

I have seen people asked a similar question but not exactly the same, and the suggested solutions I have seen did not really work for me.

**My current issue**
My tomcat prints out the following log message containing exception as long as there is a Struts 2 web app published. 
And I can load the right page for localhost:8080 but not the web app, even though the war folder is already placed inside the webapps folder of Tomcat.

I guess it's related to the servlet-api.jar, but I have made sure that jar is inside the Tomcat lib folder, and that Tomcat folder is being pointed by my Eclipse Tomcat server.

I am using Mac OSX and I am also sure my env variables are in place. By typing export in the terminal, I can see the value of CATALINA_BASE, CATALINA_HOME, CLASSPATH etc.

So I need help..

Server message:

```
Nov 28, 2013 1:59:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
Nov 28, 2013 1:59:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HellowWorldStruts2' did not find a matching property.
Nov 28, 2013 1:59:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 28, 2013 1:59:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 28, 2013 1:59:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 659 ms
Nov 28, 2013 1:59:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 28, 2013 1:59:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:01 PM org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci onStartup
INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocketJARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available. 
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1617)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 31 more
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/HellowWorldStruts2] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/docs
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/examples
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@37e80c87')
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/host-manager
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/manager
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/ROOT
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 28, 2013 2:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4323 ms
```

Solution: I found out I copied my entire Struts2 jar library to my /Library/Java/Extensions folder. I remove all those jars, and this error is gone (new error..)

Comment: From [the FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Class_Not_Found#Q2) : `You probably have servlet-api.jar floating around somewhere it shouldn't be. This really messes up the classloaders since Tomcat's classloaders don't act quite as normal as one expects (see links above). servlet-api.jar should only be found only once in $CATALINA_HOME/lib.`  Could it be that somehow that jar is also packaged in your WAR?

Comment: I checked and didn't really have duplicated jar file in my WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 2):

`NoClassDefFoundError`'s on Tomcat like this one are almost always the result of conflicting versions of `servlet-api.jar`--typically between your *WEB-INF\lib* and Tomcat's *lib* folder.

Make sure you don't have `servlet-api.jar` in *WEB-INF\lib* by setting the appropriate scope in your build tool (if applicable--for example, `provided` in Maven or `providedRuntime` or `providedCompile` in Gradle).

Comment: I verified there is no servlet-api.jar in my WAR's WEB-INF/lib. Under the Tomcat's root folder, it's only available under Tomcat's lib folder.

Comment: And by the way, I am not using any build tool but the simplest way that comes with Eclipse, just to publish it onto Tomcat.

Comment: Then check Tomcat's lib folder for jars that might contain conflicting Servlet stuff. Since you're on Mac, try [Jarzilla](https://code.google.com/p/jarzilla/). Also, make sure `Filter` is available where you think it is.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. Something I don't think is relevant, but just would like to mention. There is another servlet-api.jar coming from my Google App Engine eclipse plugin. It is stored in a totally different location and never referenced. I don't think that's the cause?

Comment: As long as it isn't in the runtime classpath, you're OK. But I'm telling you that is the kind of stuff that causes weirdness, so make sure it isn't messing with you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```